# Running Cython install generates unwanted files

Tags: python, cython, distutils, extension-modules

I am currently creating a python library for my python projects, and I require certain things to run much faster than normal python can, and Cython is the only way I can think to do this.

I have created a setup.py file and have tried multiple methods of achieving the cython build:

I have used

```py
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

# Note filePath is the directory to the .pyx file, not a variable
setup(ext_modules=cythonize(filePath))
```

Running `python setup.py install` builds the extension, and then installs it, however, it also generates many extra folders and files from previous projects where I have used cython. I only expected the file I had given it to be created into an extension module.

I have tried different methods for creating the extension files, however, none of them do anything different and they all give the same results: loads of folders and files being created in my project that I didn't ask for.

Any help as to how I should solve this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Some of this can be solved with `python3 setup.py clean` which is just a standard distutils command. It doesn't remove the Cython ".c" files though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this issue,

It turns out that Cython treats files with the same name as the same projects, so simply changing the name of my project was enough to fix it. This is not intuitive, though in a way it makes sense.

I hope this helps anyone who comes across this problem.